# QuerySet to get top x of something - Django

Tags: python, django

first time here, so please be nice (?

I want to be able to show a Top X of most commented posts in the index of my website.

```
#models.py

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey("auth.User", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
```

```
#views.py

def index(request):
    top_comm = #I know it has to be Django aggregation, but I can't make it.
    return render(request, 'home/index.html', {"top_comm" : top_comm})
```

```
#index.html

{% for row in top_comm %}

{{row.author|linebreaksbr}}
{{row.text|linebreaksbr}}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What are *alojamientos*? How do you order your set?

Comment: You can order and slice a queryset if that’s what you mean

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem edited, it was posts instead of alojamientos

Comment: @geremiasdurand: so you want to show posts which are most commented?

Comment: @IainShelvington how can I do that?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem exactly that

Answer (score 1):

I might have misunderstood, but I think you want .annotate().

```
from django.db.models import Count

TOP_POST_LIMIT = 10

def index(request):
    top_comm = Post.objects.annotate(c_count=Count('comment')).order_by('-c_count')[:TOP_POST_LIMIT]
    return render(request, 'home/index.html', {"top_comm" : top_comm})
```